# How to set a Special Price and block all coupons for it

Tags: price

Using Magento 1.4.0.1 and want to put an item on sale using a Special Price. I don't want customers to use a coupon to further discount it.  This applies to one SKU only. I have over 500 coupons so I can't go into each coupon and exclude this item.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For now I set up a coupon with conditions that is only used on the one product sku.

Comment: Via the admin GUI you have to actively exclude this item in some manner, unfortunately. This would be easily done programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the product to exclude in the rule is the best way forward, as magento core would take care of the wanted functionality for you.

You could add a new attribute to your products: skip_coupon_rule as an example.
In your rules add a condition to not apply the rule if that attribute is set.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a coupon rule, which only is for this one product, putting the priority to 0 and stop processing after this rule?